# Cannot run Mesos Containers with GPU tasks

Tags: gpu, mesos

I am running Mesos on Ubuntu and am trying to execute:

```
mesos-execute \
--master=$(cat /etc/mesos/zk) \
--name=gpu-test \
--docker_image=nvidia/cuda \
--command="nvidia-smi" \
--framework_capabilities="GPU_RESOURCES" \
--resources="gpus:1"
```

and it is failing because: `sh: 1: nvidia-smi: not found`

even though when I run it without container support

```
mesos-execute \
--master=$(cat /etc/mesos/zk) \
--name=gpu-test \
--command="nvidia-smi" \
--framework_capabilities="GPU_RESOURCES" \
--resources="gpus:1"
```

it has access to the gpu

plus if I run it without container support but put the command as

`nvidia-docker run -it nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`

it works, so it seems that the mesos containerizer doesnt have access to the GPUs. But in the `/etc/mesos-slave/` directory I gave it containerizers mesos (and all the other required flags to run gpu commands). Plus non-gpu related commands are working fine.

Comment: Can you run the Mesos GPU unit tests (`sudo bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="*NVIDIA_GPU*"`) and report the results?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a regression in 1.3.0. I downgraded to 1.2.1 on Ubuntu and can successfully use GPUs with Docker containers and the Mesos containerizer again.

```
sudo apt-get install mesos=1.2.1-2.0.1
```

It looks like someone filed a related bug but there's been no activity:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7730

Comment: thank you, yeah I forgot to edit my question. We informed the Mesos team about it.